# How to output sound through HDMI adapter (late 2008 Macbook)?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, hdmi

Is there a workaround that allows the laptop to send sound to a projector, such as using a different type of adapter?

Comment: we just use a mic on the laptop's speaker

Comment: Does the projector *not*  have multiple inputs including audio?

Answer (score 1):

There are Mini DisplayPort / USB to HDMI adaptors. The Mini DisplayPort provides the video and the USB supplies the sound.

For example:

[newertechnology](https://www.newertech.com/products/tcblmdphdmia.php)
[Monoprice](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=5969)
[StarTech](https://www.startech.com/AV/display-and-video-adapters/Displayport-Adapters/Mini-DisplayPort-to-HDMI-Adapter-with-USB-Audio~MDP2HDMIUSBA)